# Building ogre for android ndk10

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake, ogre

Sorry I may added it as another topic but I get a different error. Now I have the dependencies installed from the repository. I'm trying to build  for Android.
I use Mingw32 
 now I get the following error:

```
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libOgreSampleBrowser.so
C:/ogre/AndroidDependencies/lib/armeabi-v7a/libFreeImage.a(libraw_datastream.c
.o):libraw_datastream.cpp:function LibRaw_bigfile_datastream::get_char(): erro
 undefined reference to '__srget'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[3]: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libOgreSampleBrowser.so] Error 1
Samples\Browser\CMakeFiles\SampleBrowserDummy.dir\build.make:84: recipe for ta
et 'lib/libSampleBrowserDummy.so' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [lib/libSampleBrowserDummy.so] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:3749: recipe for target 'Samples/Browser/CMakeFiles/Sampl
rowserDummy.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Samples/Browser/CMakeFiles/SampleBrowserDummy.dir/all] E
or 2
Makefile:136: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error...
Google removed __srget starting from NDKr10c (check their official site in other fixed bugs). 
Download r10b and below and it should work.